# Is there a BUG in PHP "IF block" parsing method or what?

Tags: php, if-statement, parsing-error

Consider the following hypothetical PHP example:

```
$bar = 'bar';
$foo = 'foo';

if (isset($bar)):
   if (isset($foo)) echo "Both are set.";
elseif (isset($foo)):
   echo "Only 'foo' is set.";
else:
   echo "Only 'bar' is set.";
endif;
```

Disconsider the dumb logic and focus on the `elseif` line. If you try it yourself you will get a **PHP EXCEPTION** error saying "*syntax error, unexpected ':'* "

Now, you may think the fix is to have the sub-`if` enclosed in between `{ }` instead of being a single line statement, like this:

```
$foo = 'foo';
$bar = 'bar';

if (isset($bar)):
   if (isset($foo)) {
     echo "Both are set.";
   }
elseif (isset($foo)):
   echo "Only 'foo' is set.";
else:
   echo "Only 'bar' is set.";
endif;
```

Wrong! The error remains. Exactly the same **EXCEPTION** as before...

So, what is wrong with those examples?

Answer (score 1):

Well, here is what I found: if you put a semicolon (`;`) **AFTER** the curly bracket (`}`) which resides immediately before the `elseif` statement, then the error is gone! Try it:

```
$foo = 'foo';
$bar = 'bar';

if (isset($bar)):
   if (isset($foo)) {
     echo "Both are set.";
   };
elseif (isset($foo)):
   echo "Only 'foo' is set.";
else:
   echo "Only 'bar' is set.";
endif;
```

Weird enough, if you go back to the first example and DOUBLE the semicolon immediately before the `elseif` statement, it will also work:

```
$foo = 'foo';
$bar = 'bar';

if (isset($bar)):
  if (isset($foo)) echo "Both are set.";;
elseif (isset($foo)):
  echo "Only 'foo' is set.";
else:
  echo "Only 'bar' is set.";
endif;
```

But, it doesn't end there. You can also do this:

```
$foo = 'foo';
$bar = 'bar';

if (isset($bar)):
  if (isset($foo)): echo "Both are set.";
elseif (isset($foo)):
  echo "Only 'foo' is set.";
else:
  echo "Only 'bar' is set.";
endif;
```

However, in this last example, the logic gets totally scrambled! The `elseif` will now belong to the sub-`if` instead of the first `if`, and the rest of the logic will all behave as a "one single statement" in response to the first `if` only. Very confusing and error prone (be careful).

The differences are very subtle and can deceive the eyes (especially while debugging). For this reason, I strongly suggest the first example from this answer: when using IF-ELSEIF blocks (AKA "Alternative Syntax"), if another IF is required inside it, enclose it in between `{}` and don't forget to add a semicolon after the last `}`. Example:

```
if (isset($bar)):
   if (isset($foo)) {
     echo "Both are set.";
   };
elseif (...):
```

Maybe the truth is that someone screwed up in the language parsing process for those PHP Block Alternative Statements or failed to document this **very important** detail!

Comment: Actually it's [documented](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php): "Note: Mixing syntaxes in the same control block is not supported."

Comment: Please develop a coding style that does not look like this. I hate when people try to force a coding style on me, and I'm not doing that, Its just not clean, clear, or good. This is the kind of thing a person would see in Wordpress code.

Comment: Please, READ before comment!!!!!

Go back to the FIRST example (in the question). Try it. Explain the error.

Then, check the DOUBLE semi colon example in the answer. Try it. Explain it. 

The whole point of this post was exactly to explain the problem in question, not to discuss code style, the cuteness of design or personal preference.

Comment: @GrasDouble, "mixing is not supported" refers to the usage of  "{}" with "alternative blocks" in the SAME level. For sub-levels it is allowed. You should try the example to assure it works (or not) before providing wrongful interpretation of the manual wordings.

I didn't write the interpreter, either the coding rules. I am simply challenging people to think about those nuances, in special the parsing misinterpretation described in the QUESTION. This answer simply shows "options that worked" (when those that should be the right ones failed).

Comment: I also thought of the "same level" thing, though I think it's safe to assume the interpreter is just not smart enough to handle some cases with mixed syntaxes. Note that if you put the "alternate syntax" conditions in separate `<?php ?>` blocks (like it's often done in "view/template" files), it works.

Comment: @GrasDouble, now you got it. However, back to the first example (from the question), the level of complexity is little to none, and it still fails, which is a huge problem! Nice catch about the "separate PHP blocks" context. I will try it too.